# Specific variables in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a while loop for db output, there are two query results and I want to assign table_id variables to $_SESSION["var"], but the problem is that only last table_id, "2" for example is stored in $_SESSION["var"].

```
<?php
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $_SESSION["id"] = $rows["nekretnina_id"]; ?></td>
 <td><a href ="http://localhost/getin/pages/in/result_fin.php"><?php echo $rows["naziv"]; ?></a></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["tip_naziv"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["kvadratura"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["terasa"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["grejanje"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["opis"]; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $rows["cena"]; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

So when I click on link, it always takes me to page for second result. How can I add each of table_ids to specific var or $_SESSION["var"]?

```
$s = " select * from nekretnina
       INNER JOIN grad ON nekretnina.grad_id=grad.grad_id
       INNER JOIN tip ON nekretnina.tip_id=tip.tip_id where nekretnina_id = 
       '".$_SESSION["id"][2]."' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign as an array

```
$_SESSION["id"][]=$rows["nekretnina_id"];
```

Then the entries will need to be accessed as you would with an array

```
echo $_SESSION["id"][1]; //etc
```

To use the stored IDs later to forumulate other SQL queries ideally you should use `prepared statements` to help mitigate the risk of sql injection attacks. The following  two nisppets show different approaches that you might take in this case though I stress that neither are tested and my have typos / syntax errors as they were very quickly written.

```
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){

    $_SESSION["id"][] = $rows["nekretnina_id"];
    /* other code */
}
```

Assumed database connection object is called `$con`

There are at least two ways in which this select statement can be done

The first selects each record by the ID stored in the session

```
$sql='select * 
        from `nekretnina` n
        inner join grad g on n.grad_id=g.grad_id 
        inner join tip t on n.tip_id=t.tip_id 
        where n.nekretnina_id=?';

$stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param( 'i', $id );

    foreach( $_SESSION["id"][] as $id ){
        $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( $res ){
            $res=$stmt->get_result();

            /* process recordset */
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                echo $rs->name; // assumed column `name` in results
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second would use a single SQL query with a range of IDs to choose from using the `IN` operator

```
$sql='select * 
        from `nekretnina` n
        inner join grad g on n.grad_id=g.grad_id 
        inner join tip t on n.tip_id=t.tip_id 
        where n.nekretnina_id in ( ? )';
$stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

$idrange = sprintf( "'%s'", implode( ',', $_SESSION["id"] ) );

$stmt->bind_param( 's', $idrange );
$res=$stmt->execute();
if( $res ){
    $res=$stmt->get_result();
    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
        echo $rs->name; // assumed column `name` in results
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it works, but later on result_fin page where query is executed, I have to manually set parameters in WHERE clause:

    $s = " select * from nekretnina
               INNER JOIN grad ON nekretnina.grad_id=grad.grad_id
               INNER JOIN tip ON nekretnina.tip_id=tip.tip_id where nekretnina_id = 
               '".$_SESSION["id"][2]."' ";
How can I actually just compare variable from while loop without setting any array indexes because maybe there could be like 10 or 20 results, so I would have to write query for each.

Comment: well firstly do NOT embed the variables directly within your sql... If you can add that sql in a formatted version to the question I'll make a change above to show how you can do it

Comment: I added the code in question